# Q: wx MouseEvent doing nothing

Tags: python, mouseevent, wxwidgets

So im been working a little while with wx on python.
For my problem I made a little code in order to show you what i need.

```
import wx
while True:
if wx.MouseEvent().LeftIsDown() == True:
    print True
```

I have been trying several variations with no results.
Hope u can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The event objects are not meant to be created by user.

It is created by the wx framework, when there is a relevant event, like when user clicked the mouse, keyboard, button clicked, ....

You need to set up event binding.

See [Events and Event Handling - wxPython documentation](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/events_overview.html).

Comment: Ok, so It seems I was a little confused with that. 
thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

So I re wrote the code. I needed to check the state of the mouse.
The correct way was:

```
if  wx.GetMouseState().LeftIsDown() == True:
```